How to create a single CSV file with specified file name Spark in Databricks?
I know how to use Spark in Databricks to create a CSV, but it always has lots of side effects.
For example, here is my code:
file_path = “dbfs:/mnt/target_folder/file.csv”
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv(file_path, header=True)

Then what I got is

A folder with name file.csv
In the folder there are addtional files called _committed_xxxx, _started_xxxx, _SUCCESS
Multiple files with part-xxxx

What I want is only a SINGLE CSV file with the name file.csv, how can I achieve this?
I tried to use pandas.to_csv function, but it’s not working on Databricks notebook, the error is

OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory


This question is similar to: How to save a spark DataFrame as csv on disk?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

We can split the issues discussed,
Issue 1: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory
Can be addressed if you check if directory exists first and then create the file,
directory = "/dbfs/mnt/target_folder/"
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

pdf = df.toPandas()

file_path = os.path.join(directory, "file.csv")
pdf.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

Issue 2: Multiple files with part-xxxx
Using coalesce can solve this.
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv(file_path, header=True)

Issue 3: Having metadata files like _committed_xxxx, _started_xxxx, _SUCCESS
You can use Databricks file system utilities
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/mnt/target_folder/part-00000-*.csv","dbfs:/mnt/target_folder/file.csv")
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/target_folder/part-00000-*.csv")
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/target_folder/_*")

